# How can I see the full name of NIC properties?

Tags: windows, networking, user-interface

In the English version of my NIC properties dialog, I can read all settings just fine:

[image]

But on localized systems, there can be a slightly different picture:

[image]

What exactly is the difference between the first and the second property? How can I find out? The dialog can't be resized and the entries have no tooltips either.

Comment: Reset smaller DPI may be, but I think the missing part is (IPv4) and (IPv6)

Comment: @Bolu Yeah, I figured it would be IPv4/6, but with other cards on other systems there are often other options which are cut off. DPI might be an interesting idea.

Comment: Or you could search any item you can see from the list in Registry Editor, and you will find all of them there.

Comment: Fantastic responsive UI design, this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nirsoft makes a program SysExporter that can extract the contents of most windows, in the windows systems.
"SysExporter" http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html
I like to call it a Window snagger, it can grab text of just about anything. titles, status, text boxes, context menus even html off a web browser.

Because it is getting the contents from the system itself , even hidden items will be able to be seen or extracted.  You could use it in this situation to see all the text that belonged in that text box.

[image]
Once it is running just drag that target circle to the exact location you want to grab.

Tips from using it:

- You may have to Run_As Administrator.
- It helps to have other stuff
  closed, and minimal things going on in other windows generally, it
  will even lock-up (not responding) on my machine with too many things
  going on and being updated.

  - It might help to turn off AutoRefresh in the Options menu.
  - Filters can be applied in the filters menu.

Without sounding like an ad, tools like this can come in handy for
   many other purposes, a good one to have in your utility closet :-)

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to Run as administrator.